# C# foreach within foreach, display 3 item in each item. carousel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach, carousel

I am using asp.net MVC 4 for my project, and I have a Model.
and I am using Bootstrap Carousel to show products for my Index Page (see the image below)

Now my question is: I want to show 3 Products in each slide item.
should I write a ViewModel for this?

```
<div class="carousel slide>
  @for (int i = 0; i <= Model.Count()/3; i++ ) <!-- this works well, paging -->
    {
      <div class="item @if(i==0){<text>active</text>}">
        @foreach(var well in Model)
        {
            <div class="span4">
                <!-- some html here -->
            </div>
        }
      </div>
    }
</div>
```

[image: carousel]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your inner `foreach` is iterating over the entire `Model` collection - you'll need to restrict it to just the relevant three items.

I'm guessing you want something like:

```
<div class="carousel slide>
    @for (int i = 0; i <= Model.Count()/3; i++ ) <!-- this works well, paging -->
    {
        <div class="item @if(i==0){<text>active</text>}">
        @foreach(var well in Model.Skip(i*3).Take(3))
        {
            <div class="span4">
                <!-- some html here -->
            </div>
        }
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, Your are saved my Life... and you are guessing right. it works perfectly!....

Answer (score 2):

One way to think about this problem is to split the original collection into groups for each 3 sequential elements. Fortunately, you can use the `GroupBy` LINQ method using the "element index divided by 3" as key. IMO, the advantage of this solution is that it expresses more clearly your intent and has better performance than reiterating the collection with `Skip(x * 3).Take(3)` in the inner loop.

```
<div class="carousel slide>
    @foreach (var group in Model.Select((x, index) => new { element = x, index }).GroupBy(x => x.index / 3, x => x.element))
    {
        <div class="item @if( group.Key == 0) {<text>active</text>}">
        @foreach(var well in group)
        {
            <div class="span4">
                <!-- some html here -->
            </div>
        }
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

I would even change the model type to `ILookup<int, TElement>` and perform the grouping in the controller.